# Problems with scanning in java

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I got a task, where I have to calculate the perimeter and area of a given object, that's determined by the user, with accompanying data - side length, radius, etc. To do this I have to do a "GUI" as my teacher said, and to do that, I have to use the Scanner.

Everytime I try to do the second scan, after the user has choosen what object we are dealing with, when it gets to the part, where the user's supposed to input their data about their object, it always crashes, with a java.util.NoSuchElementException error, according to NetBeans. I looked through it, and even copied in the working scanner, but to no avail.

Here's the full code:

```
package Methods2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Methods2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialization
    int decider;
    Scanner input1;
    
    //defining
    input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose from these options to find the perimeter and area of any of these:\n1. Circle\n2. Square\n3. Rectangle");
    decider = input1.nextInt();
    input1.close();
    
    //decision
    if (decider == 1) {
        circle();
    } else if (decider == 2) {
        square();
    } else if (decider == 3) {
        rectangle();
    } else {
        System.out.println("There aren't any other options, other than these three.");
    }
}
public static void circle() {
    //method specific initialization
    int radius;
    double pi;
    double perimeter;
    double area;
    Scanner input2;
    
    //define
    pi = 3.14;
    input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type in the radius of the circle!");
    radius = input2.nextInt(); //these are where my problem's lie
    input2.close();
    
    //calculate
    perimeter = 2 * radius * pi;
    area = radius * radius * pi;
    
    //print
    System.out.println("The perimeter of this circle is: " + perimeter);
    System.out.println("The area of this circle is: " + area);
}
public static void square() {
    //method specific initialization
    int a;
    int perimeter;
    int area;
    Scanner input3;
    
    //define
    input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type in one side's length of the square!");
    a = input3.nextInt(); //these are where my problem's lie
    input3.close();
    
    //calculate
    perimeter = 4 * a;
    area = a * a;
    
    //print
    System.out.println("The perimeter of this circle is: " + perimeter);
    System.out.println("The area of this circle is: " + area);
}
public static void rectangle() {
    //method specific initialization
    int a;
    int b;
    int perimeter;
    int area;
    Scanner input4;
    
    //define
    input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type in one of the sides' length of the rectangle!");
    a = input4.nextInt(); //these are where my problem's lie
    System.out.println("Now type the other, non-equal side, compared to the previous one!");
    b = input4.nextInt(); //these are where my problem's lie
    input4.close();
    
    //calculate
    perimeter = 2 * (a + b);
    area = a * b;
    
    //print
    System.out.println("The perimeter of this circle is: " + perimeter);
    System.out.println("The area of this circle is: " + area);
}
}
```

I have thought about it being multiple Scanner's, but after I realized, that variables don't carry over between methods, unless they're defined within the class, that was swiftly thrown out as a theory. Also, NetBeans didn't mark any problems with that line, so it made even less sense to me.

Comment: If you're closing the `Scanner`, it closes its underlying input stream, in your case `System.in`. If it's closed, you cannot use it to feed a new `Scanner` (in your shape methods). Remove the `input1.close()` or keep the same `Scanner` to read further input.

Comment: 1. Methods don't have to be `void`, they can `return` things that you want out of them.  2. Methods can have parameters, so you can pass things between them without storing them as fields.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I will remove the close. As for the return or void; our teacher doesn't really like if we include anything that we haven't learned yet in our code, especially not for tests. While I appreciate the tip, I can't really use it as of now, yet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is "stopping" the scanner, is because you added `input1.close();`. What `.close()` does, is that it closes the scanner. Once a scanner is closed, you won't be able to open it again. According to your code, you use the Scanner.. even after it was closed. So to fix your problem, removed the line:

```
input1.close();
```

**Here is a close up of where you should remove the line:**

```
 //initialization
    int decider;
    Scanner input1;
    
    //defining
    input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose from these options to find the perimeter and area of any of these:\n1. Circle\n2. Square\n3. Rectangle");
    decider = input1.nextInt();
    //input1.close(); REMOVE THIS LINE
```